# git aliases causing "Permission denied" error

Tags: git

The following commands

```
$ git co -b newbranch
$ git co oldbranch
```

result in "fatal: cannot exec 'git-co': Permission denied" error.

In the same time,

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch
$ git checkout oldbranch
```

and

```
$ sudo git co -b newbranch
$ sudo git co oldbranch
```

work as expected. Ownership rights for the .git folder are set for the user owning the home folder and 0755/0644 are the mode for .git folder/subfolder/files. There are no `git-co` script anywhere in the system (that is an expandable alias to `git-checkout`, which resides in /usr/libexec/git-core` dir).

Aliases are defined in `.gitconfig` of the home folder:

```
[alias]
co = checkout
```

There is no difference in `git config -l` output for root or unprivileged user. Still `sudo git co oldbranch` works and `git co oldbranch` does not.

What am I missing?

Gentoo / kernel 3.0.6 / git 1.7.3.4

Comment: where are the aliases? are they invoking scripts?

Comment: Attach the output of `git config --get-regexp '^alias\.'`

Comment: @AlexeiDanchenkov: erm... not to state the obvious but "where are the aliases" (we can't _see_ them)

Comment: Look in your git install directory; I don't know gentoo but it's probably `/usr/libexec/git-core`, `/usr/lib/git-core` or one of those with `/usr` changed to `/usr/local`. You should see a bunch of executable files for all the git commands. See if there's also a `git-co` in there, which is executable by root but not by you. Possibly this could also happen if this `git-co` file is somewhere in your `PATH`. It might also be locatable with `sudo which git-co`, if it's not in the git install directory.

Comment: @mahojlds `alias.co checkout`

Comment: @Jefromi No, this is not the case. There is no such file as `git-co` anywhere in the system. `sudo which git-co` confirms that with `which: no git-co in (...)`

Comment: Wait, why is root even seeing the alias? `sudo git ...` should look for gitconfig in *root*'s git config, not yours. Have you possibly mixed something up there?

Comment: Root does "see" the alias, but it is not `git-co` script. It does expand the `git-co` to `git-checkout`, and yes, the `git-checkout` is in /usr/libexec/gitcore. There is no difference between the .gitconfig file contents in /root and unprivileged user's home dir, except the owner/group.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The correct answer to this was actually different. Before git runs the aliases it checks the `$PATH`. In case the directory does not exist, or lacks permissions, git produces the `"fatal: cannot exec 'git-co': Permission denied"`. It does not ever comes to check the aliases so `git foobar` will produce the same error.

Good people from the git mailing list also reminded me of an `strace` tool, that can help finding the entry that is returning EACCES, as in: `strace -f -e execve git foobar`

The credit goes to Jeff King from the git mailing list. :)

Comment: I'm on Gentoo w/ git 1.7.3.4 and no public execute permissions on /usr/games/bin was causing this for me. It was in my path and Git failed to find proper permissions on a dir in my PATH so it produced this error for an alias. `chmod +x /usr/games/bin` was all it took to fix it right up for me. Grabbed this one-liner to quickly view PATH permissions `echo $PATH |tr ':' '\n' |xargs ls -ld`

Comment: Good catch! Glad you found the right answer. Sure enough, adding a directory to `PATH` that does not have execute permissions set will cause running git with a non-builtin command to give a `fatal: cannot exec 'git-hist': Permission denied` error. I'm using Git version 1.7.8; hopefully a fix will be available soon.

Comment: or better yet:  strace -f -e execve git foobar 2>&1|grep -i denied

Comment: Exactly my issue, too. My PATH is preset with dozens of dirs (only a few of which are bad) sourced from /etc scripts out of my control (e.g., remote storage not always available). To quickly reset the path to just valid dirs: `PATH=$(for d in ${PATH//:/ } ; do [ -x $d ] && printf "$d\n"; done | uniq | tr '\12' ':')` (and to trim the trailing `:`, follow with `PATH=${PATH%?}`)

Comment: What do you mean when you say an entry that is returning "EACCES"?

Comment: @camdixon For example, check this list of system errors: http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html. The original issue was about a file access error, which should not have been there in a first place.

Answer (score 8):

Is it possible you have inadvertently created a non-executable `git-co` file somewhere? I can recreate your situation if I do just that, as demonstrated below.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.7.1.475.g997a1
$ git config --get-regexp '^alias\.co$'
alias.co checkout
$ git co b1
Switched to branch 'b1'
$ touch $HOME/bin/git-co
$ ls -al $HOME/bin/git-co
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2011-11-03 12:59 /home/user/bin/git-co
$ git co master
fatal: cannot exec 'git-co': Permission denied
$ for p in $(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:/ /g'); do if [ -f "${p}/git-co" ]; then echo "Found git-co in ${p}"; fi; done
Found git-co in /home/user/bin
$ rm $HOME/bin/git-co
rm: remove regular empty file `/home/user/bin/git-co'? y
$ git co master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

Another thing you might want to try is enabling trace logging to get more information about what Git is doing. Following is an example:

```
GIT_TRACE=$HOME/trace.log git co master
```

You must use **absolute** paths if you want to send output to a file. Otherwise, use `true` or `1` to send output to standard error; e.g. `GIT_TRACE=1`. The `trace.log` file contains:

```
trace: exec: 'git-co' 'master'
trace: run_command: 'git-co' 'master'
trace: alias expansion: co => 'checkout'
trace: built-in: git 'checkout' 'master'
```

If you do not see the `trace: alias expansion: co=> 'checkout'` trace log output, Git is finding a `git-co` file in the `PATH` environment variable. Git uses a `PATH` as follows:

1. Start with an empty `PATH`, saving any "old" `PATH` for reference.
2. If the `--exec-path=<my git commands path>` Git option is found, append `<my git commands path>` to the `PATH`.
3. If `--exec-path=<my git commands path>` was not found and the `GIT_EXEC_PATH` environment variable is set, append this to the `PATH`.
4. If you called `git` using a relative or absolute path, append the absolute path of the `git` executable to the `PATH`.
5. If `PATH` was previously defined, append it to the `PATH`.
6. If `PATH` was not previously defined, append `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` to the `PATH`.

You can use another alias to get Git to tell you what it is setting the `PATH` environment variable to.

```
$ git config --global alias.whatpath '!echo $PATH'
$ git whatpath
/usr/local/libexec/git-core:/home/user/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Then check each directory listed for the existence of a `git-co` file. It's not sufficient to do `which git-co` and assume that if nothing is found that you do not have a `git-co` file located in one of the directories in Git's `PATH`; a file may exist that is not executable and `which` will not display it.

Comment: This is not the case. I checked this already, but nope... The for loop in your example returns nothing.

Comment: You could also check for a `git-co` file in the directory that `git --exec-path` displays. As well as using `find / -name git-co` to check your whole system (obviously, use with care).

Comment: Thanks, Dan. There is a `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-checkout` file with proper permissions, but there us no `git-co` anywhere. My assumption is that the alias is not working. But it works for root... Getting desperate.

Comment: Dan, that was closer, the trace.log stops at step 3 (alias expansion), i.e. the `trace: alias expansion: co => 'checkout'` never appears for an unprivileged user. It does for the root. The traceSetup.log never appears in neither case.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have execute permissions on the git aliases.
Providing the execute permissions solved this issue for me.

I downloaded "git-credential-osxkeychain" and added it to /usr/local/bin and provided the exec rights and could run the command without any issue.